# facing issue while running protractor-cucumber framework

Tags: protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

Sir, I am trying to run file using protractor cucumber framework by using 
async and await concept it passes all my tests but it always gives error 
regarding angular testability and I don't know why it gives such a type of 
error, please read the code below once and help me to figure out where I am 
wrong in this approach.

**Please refer below my feature file** :-

[image: featurefile]

**Please refer my pageobjects file as below** :-

[image: pageobject file]

**Please refer step-definition file as below**:-

[image: stepdefinitionfile]

**Please refer configuration file conf.ts as below** :-

[image: configurationfile]

**Please refer console logs as below**:-

```
[12:31:48] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[12:31:48] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:54978/devtools/browser/3cec07ae-0398-49b1-8fd9-36607b210799
...Menu 9 option reached
..

1 scenario (1 passed)
4 steps (4 passed)
0m00.034s
(node:2484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a
non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
    at runWaitForAngularScript.then (E:\Backup_work\Protractor projects\cucumber2_framework\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:463:23)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)Error
    at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (E:\Backup_work\Protractor projects\cucumber2_framework\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:459:27)
    at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function).args [as click] (E:\Backup_work\Protractor projects\cucumber2_framework\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:91:29)
    at ElementFinder.(anonymous function).args [as click] (E:\Backup_work\Protractor projects\cucumber2_framework\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:831:22)
    at homepageclass.clickEXWmenu (E:\Backup_work\Protractor projects\cucumber2_framework\pageobjects\menu9.PO.js:10:29)
    at World.<anonymous> (E:\Backup_work\Protractor projects\cucumber2_framework\Stepdefinition\first.steps.js:22:20)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at E:\Backup_work\Protractor projects\cucumber2_framework\Stepdefinition\first.steps.js:7:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (E:\Backup_work\Protractor projects\cucumber2_framework\Stepdefinition\first.steps.js:3:12)
    at World.<anonymous> (E:\Backup_work\Protractor projects\cucumber2_framework\Stepdefinition\first.steps.js:21:12)
(node:2484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:2484) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:2484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a
non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2643 for details"
    at runWaitForAngularScript.then (E:\Backup_work\Protractor projects\cucumber2_framework\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:463:23)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)Error
    at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (E:\Backup_work\Protractor projects\cucumber2_framework\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:459:27)
    at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function).args [as click] (E:\Backup_work\Protractor projects\cucumber2_framework\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:91:29)
    at ElementFinder.(anonymous function).args [as click] (E:\Backup_work\Protractor projects\cucumber2_framework\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:831:22)
    at homepageclass.clickmenu9 (E:\Backup_work\Protractor projects\cucumber2_framework\pageobjects\menu9.PO.js:13:26)
    at World.<anonymous> (E:\Backup_work\Protractor projects\cucumber2_framework\Stepdefinition\first.steps.js:26:10)
(node:2484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
[12:31:50] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[12:31:50] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
```

Comment: This error is most typically seen when some part of your application is non-angular. Do you know if your application has any parts like this, such as a third-party provided login screen?

Comment: @keshav - try adding browser.ignoreSynchrosisation = true; in your configuration file, your application might be non-angular, by adding above command it wont for an angular page.

Comment: @Parthi my application is angular application and I have tried by adding browser.ignoresynchronization=true but then it gives error for nosuchelementexception and also I get UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().

Comment: @Parthi please refer this link to get an idea of what exactly happens when we add ignoresynchronization=true,   https://pasteboard.co/I4VBe5q.png

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem here is you are using await but the function you are using await on is not async.

```
public async clickEXWMenu(){
   await this.EXWenquirymenu.click();
}
```

This is how it should be ^

Comment: Thank you I will try it out and let you know

Comment: I am still facing isue of nosuchelement exception for the element of second function and also I have to use browserignoresynchronization=true even in angular app please refer link:- https://pasteboard.co/I521XYU.png

Comment: Have you added async await to the clickMenu9 method?  
It looks like a legit error now in that the element is not being found. Can you try doing a find element on a simple element that you are sure is there and confirm if protractor finds it

Comment: I have added async await in clickmenu9 method see the image https://pasteboard.co/I5bzSCC.png

Comment: @keshavdwivedi and still the same issue? Have you got this project on a repo somewhere? So I can run the code?

Comment: this website is of my company and only runs on computers connected from company domain even if I will give you the project code then also you will not be able to see the website opening and code running because on your computer it will give 404 error. but then also I have uploaded on the following github repo https://github.com/keshavdwivedi/protractor-cucumber-framework/tree/master/.install nnode modules by npm install and change the code as per your convenience  so as to solve the error.I thank you for your efforts. Please be in touch with me on my skype_id :- keshav.dwivedi17

Comment: the above Skype ID is now changed to :- keshu.dwivedi17 please connect on this id